# How do I iterate through a list within a list and then create a csv at the end?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have a code that produces scraped data and puts it in 4 lists of data but I want to put them all together as a data frame and output the final result as a csv.
Also the guest column contains multiple people so how do I iterate through that list?
Not sure why my current code isn't working but its probably something quite simple.
Thanks

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import numpy as np

page = requests.get("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_QI_episodes")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "lxml")
my_tables = soup.find_all("table",{"class":"wikitable plainrowheaders wikiepisodetable"})
for table in my_tables:
    table_rows = table.find_all("tr")
    for tr in table_rows:
        td = tr.find_all("td")
        row = [i.text for i in td]
        if len(td) == 4:
            NoInSeason = td[0].find(text=True)
            Guests = td[1].find(text=True)
            Winner  = td[2].find(text=True)
            OriginalAirDate = td[3].find(text=True)     
            df = pd.DataFrame(np.column_stack([NoInSeason, Guests, Winner, OriginalAirDate]), 
             columns=['NumberInSeason', 'Guests', 'Winner', 'OriginalAirDate'])
            print(df)
            df.to_csv("output.csv")
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a few errors. Here is a fixed version of your code.

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=(['NoInSeason', 'Guests', 'Winner', 'OriginalAirDate']))
page = requests.get("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_QI_episodes")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "lxml")
my_tables = soup.find_all("table",{"class":"wikitable plainrowheaders wikiepisodetable"})
for table in my_tables:
    table_rows = table.find_all("tr")
    for tr in table_rows:
        td = tr.find_all("td")
        if len(td) == 5:
            NoInSeason = td[0].find(text=True)
            Guests = td[2].find(text=True)
            Winner  = td[3].find(text=True)
            OriginalAirDate = td[4].find(text=True) 
            df = df.append({'NoInSeason': NoInSeason, 'Guests' : Guests, 'Winner': Winner, 'OriginalAirDate' : OriginalAirDate}, ignore_index=True)
print(df)
df.to_csv("output.csv")
```

Comment: Change td[2].find(text=True) to td[2].get_text(). The find is finding the first text element get_text() finds them all. Beware output is utf-8 if you want some other encoding you will have to change it.